# getting "Unable to continue. Please install sudo before proceeding." when running command in heroku cli

Tags: heroku, newrelic

getting "Unable to continue.  Please install sudo before proceeding." error when running command to install new relic

Comment: Are you following the instructions on https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/accounts/install-new-relic/partner-based-installation/heroku-install-new-relic-add/? Or some other guide? On Heroku you're not generally gonna be running a command on the server itself.

Comment: @ceejayoz I am trying to run the following command in the Heroku cmd based on the new relic setup guide for nodejs application ```curl -Ls https://download.newrelic.com/install/newrelic-cli/scripts/install.sh | bash && sudo NEW_RELIC_API_KEY=xxxxxx NEW_RELIC_ACCOUNT_ID=xxxx /usr/local/bin/newrelic install -n node-agent-installer```

Comment: Again, follow the instructions. Heroku is **not** like other hosting providers; there are significant differences that mean running commands in `heroku run` will have **no impact** on the production servers. As you've discovered, `sudo` isn't even available there. Read https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/agents/nodejs-agent/hosting-services/nodejs-agent-heroku/ for a Heroku Node app specifically and follow *those* steps instead. A normal guide will not function on Heroku.